# Expected value for non-overlapping consecutive heads in biased coin flips

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

Toss a biased coin $n$ times with a probability $p$ to land tails. What is the expected value for occurrences of $m$ consecutive heads that don't overlap with each other? We call the amount of those occurrences $X_m$.

What is meant by non-overlapping? It means that for the permutation $HHH$ we say $X_2=1$ because it only has $1$ separate occurrence of $2$ consecutive heads rather than $2$ occurrences that would overlap with each other. In contrast we can say in $HHHH$ that $X_1=4$, $X_2=2$, $X_3=1$, $X_4=1$, and $X_5=0$.

There are multiple ways on how to actually solve this. I decided to go by this:
$$E(X_m)=\sum_{b=1}^{\infty}P(X_m \ge b)$$

In reality I only need to go until $n$ instead of $\infty$ given that $m \ge 1$ for this problem. The actual challenge for me is to find $P(X_m \ge b)$ because it seems to depend on $n$ and $m$.

The first thing I tried to do is counting all permutations (by brute forcing) where $b=1$ occurrences of $m$ consecutive heads exist in $n$ coin tosses and calculating the probability for them. I then proceeded to do the same for $b=2$ trying to find a pattern and extracting a formula.
What I found was:
\begin{align}
&\begin{aligned}
&b=1 \land n \ge m \land n\le 2m \\
&\qquad \to P(X_m \ge b)=((n-m)p+1)(1-p)^m \end{aligned}\\
&\begin{aligned}
&b=2 \land n \ge 2m \land n\le 3m \\
&\qquad \to P(X_m \ge b)=\left[\binom{n-m}{2}p^2+2(n-m)p+1\right](1-p)^{2m}\end{aligned}
\end{align}
The most important fact about those relations is the condition $n\le (b+1)m$. As $n$ goes beyond that limit, the patterns break and I cannot figure out how to determine $P(X_m \ge b)$ for an arbitrary high number of $n$. As an example:
$$
b=1 \land n=5 \land m=2 \to P(X_m \ge b)=(-p^3+2p^2+2p+1)(1-p)^m
$$

How can I go about this problem of finding the correct number of permutations with their given probabilities? Or should I try a completely other way? I want a formula for $E(X_m)$ because I want to know what $\lim_{n \to \infty} E(X_m)/n$ is.

Comment: So, for a run of $k$ consecutive heads, you count $\lfloor k/2\rfloor.$

Comment: @CalvinLin In the end I would like to know both, but primarily I want to know the expected value. (edited the title)

Comment: The first thing that occurs to me is a Markov chain, where the state is $0,$ $1,$ or $2$ if there are $0,$ $1$ or $2$ non-overlapping heads in a row.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Not quite, you need to encode all the number of non-overlapping heads at the end as states. My split into even/odd heads at the end helps to deal with this.

Comment: @CalvinLin that was what I meant.

Comment: It appears you two are trying to solve for $p=0.5$ and $m=2$? I am trying to find a solution for any value of those parameters.

Comment: What does $X_m$ count? I'm confused.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It counts how many times $m$ consecutive heads exist separately in a permutation so to speak. Like $HTHHTHHH$ has $X_2=2$ and $X_3=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full answer, but a little sloppy, using Markov chains.

Consider the Markov chain with states $0,1,\dots,m$ with $0$ starting state, and transition matrix:

$$T=\begin{pmatrix}p&(1-p)&0&\cdots&0\\ p&0&1-p&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots &\vdots&0\\p&0&0&\dots&1-p\\p&(1-p)&0&\cdots&0\end{pmatrix}$$
Then we want to know how often we are in state $m,$ which is when we got the heads a multiple of $m$ times in a chain of consecutive heads.

The expected value for how often we are in state $m$ is:
The $$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&\dots&0\end{pmatrix}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} T^i\right)\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\\vdots\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$$
Is the expected number of hits of state $m,$ which is the number of non-overlapping sequences of $m$ heads.

When $m=2$ Wolfram Alpha gives me:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\end{pmatrix} T^i\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}=\frac{(1-p)^2}{2-p}\left(1-(p-1)^{i-1}\right)$$

So the sum is $$n\frac{(1-p)^2}{2-p}-\frac{(1-p)^2}{(2-p)^2}\left(1-(p-1)^n\right)$$

The limit of $E(X_2)/n$ then is $\frac{(1-p)^2}{2-p}.$

When $m=3,$ I think the limit is:

$$\frac{(1-p)^3}{p^2-3p+3}$$

**Conjecture**

It is possible that the limit is:

$$\frac{(1-p)^m}{1+(1-p)+\cdots+(1-p)^{m-1}}=\frac{p(1-p)^m}{1-(1-p)^m}=\frac{p}{(1-p)^{-m}-1}$$

As $p\to 0$ we'd expect a limit of $\frac1m,$ and we do get that, for $f(x)=(1-x)^{-m},$ $$\lim_{p\to 0} \frac{p}{f(p)-f(0)}=\frac{1}{f'(0)}=\frac{1}{m}.$$

---

I think the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is:

$$\lambda(\lambda-1)\frac{\lambda^{m}-(1-p)^m}{\lambda -(1-p)},$$ just from looking at $m=1,2,3,4.$

---

**Attempt to understand $T$**

If we write $T=pA_0+(1-p)B$ with $$A_0=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\\vdots\\1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&\cdots&0\end{pmatrix}\\B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&\cdots&0\\0&0&1&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots &\ddots&0\\
0&0&0&\cdots&1\\
0&1&0&\cdots&0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then $$A_0B=A_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\\vdots\\1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&\cdots&0\end{pmatrix}$$

For $i=0,\dots,m-1,$ $A_iB=A_{i+1}$ and $A_mB=A_1.$

Also, $BA_i=A_i.$

Also: $A_iA_j=A_j.$

So $$T^k=(pA_0+(1-p)B)^k=(1-p)^kB^k+\sum_{i=0}^{m} c(k,i)A_k$$ for some real $c(k,i).$ You get:

$$\begin{align}  T^{k+1}&=(pA_0+(1-p)B)T^k\\&=p(1-p)^{k}A_0B^{k}+p\sum_i c(k,i)A_i+(1-p)^{k+1}B^{k+1}+(1-p)\sum_{i}c(k,i)A_i\\&=(1-p)^{k+1}B^{k+1}+p(1-p)^kA_0B^k+\sum_i c(k,i)A_i
\end{align}$$

So since $A_0B^k=A_i$ where $i=1,2,\dots,m$ has $i\equiv k\pmod m,$ you get:

$$c(k+1,i)=\begin{cases}c(k,i)+p(1-p)^k&i\neq0, i\equiv k\pmod m\\c(k,i)&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

The. $$(1,0,0,\dots,0)T^k(0,0,\dots,1)^T=(1-p)^{k}(1,0,\dots,0)B^k(0,0,\dots,1)^T+c(k,m)$$

You start with $c(1,0)=p,c(1,i)=0.$
And $$(1,0,\dots,0)B^k(0,0,\dots,1)^T=\begin{cases}1&m\mid k\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

So the expected value is:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor n/m\rfloor}(1-p)^{mj}+m\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor n/m\rfloor-1}c(mj+1,m)\right)+(n\bmod m)c(n,m)$$

And $$c(mj+1,m)=\sum_{i=1}^j p(1-p)^{mi}=\frac{p(1-p)^{m}\left(1-(1-p)^{mj}\right)}{1-(1-p)^m}$$

You get $$X_{m,n}=n\frac{p(1-p)^m}{1-(1-p)^m}+O(1).\tag1$$

From this we get my conjecture, with $q=1-p$ the probability of a heads:

$$\frac{X_{m,n}}{n}\to\frac{1-q}{q^{-m}-1}$$

---

I think there is constant $C,$ depending on $p,m,$ such that we get more specifically:

$$X_{m,n}=n\frac{p(1-p)^m}{1-(1-p)^m}+C+o(1).$$

My brain is exausted, so I’m sure I’d get wrong if I computed $C.$ You can probably replace $o(1)$ with the more specific $O\left((1-p)^n\right).$

Comment: Can you check your Markov matrix setup? At the start, I thought you were applying it on the left, so the first stage is $ T (1 \, 0 \, \ldots \, 0)^T$, but I got confused by your count for the expected value.

Comment: No, it is $(1,0,0,\dots,0)T^i.$ That is why the expected number is $$(1,0,0\dots,0)\left(\sum_{i=1}^m T^i\right)(0,0,\dots,0,1)^T.$$ My memory is fuzzy, but I thought this was pretty usual for Markov chains - that the rows add up to $1.$ @CalvinLin

Comment: You're right. I'm just more used to applying the matrix on the left (IE $Tv$), whereas you were applying it on the right (IE $vT$), hence the confusion.

Comment: @CalvinLin me too. In fact, I always get the right matrix, because I remember that, but then I often get confused about which side the “state vector” goes. I have to re-derive it.

Comment: It looks promising, and checks out with the examples I used, I just didn't have time yet to fully understand the solution yet before accepting this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note: This only deals with the case of $m=2, p = 1/2$.

Let $H_n$ be the set of $n$ coin flips that end with an odd number of $H's$, and $T_n$ be the set of $n$ coin flips that end with an even number of $H's$.

Let $ H(n) = |H_n|, T(n) = |T_n|$.
Show that $H(n+1) = T(n).$  Hint: How can we end with an odd number of heads? We definitely have to end with a H ...
Show that $ T(n+1)  = T(n) + 2H(n)$. Hint: How can we end with an even number of heads? We could end with a $T$ or ...
Show that $ H(n) = \frac{2^n - (-1)^n }{3}$, which is the closest integer to $2^n/3$.

Let $h(n)$ be the number of non-overlapping HH in $H_n$, likewise for $t(n)$. We weight by the probability of $H$ and $T$.
Show that $h(n+1) = p t(n) $.
Show that $t(n+1) = (1-p)t(n) + ph(n) +(1-p)[h(n) + H(n)] $.
So $h(n+1) + t(n+1) = 2 ( h(n) + t(n) ) + (1-p)H(n) $.
Show that $h(n+1) + t(n+1) = \frac{(3n+1)2^n - (-1)^n}{9},$ [OEIS A073371](https://oeis.org/A073371).

Hence, the expected value is $\frac{(3n-2)2^{n-1} - (-1)^{n-1}}{9 \times 2^n}$.

Comment: I am not sure how the expected value only depends purely on $n$ and not $m$ and $p$.

Comment: @aTastyT0ast Based on what you said, we went with $ m = 2$ (It was hard to interpret your post). You can adapt this (and Thomas's solution) to deal with general $m$. Also, I went with $ p = 1/2$, but you can weight the coefficients accordingly.

Comment: I don't quite get why I want to look at $H_n$ and $T_n$ in the first place I don't see the connection to the problem...

Comment: @aTastyT0ast. In the special case where $ p = 1/2$, each event is equally weighted, and hence it suffices to count the total number of non-overlapping HH without having to account for the probability that the event happens.   $\quad$ But otherwise, see Thomas's solution. That's how i would have approached it.